# Why this function return the same id?

Tags: javascript

```js
const errorListWithTheSameId = new Array(2).fill({
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
});

const correctList = [{
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
}, {
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
}];

const generate = function() {
  let uidIndex = 0;
  return function generateUniqueId(key) {
    uidIndex += 1;
    return `id-${key}-${Date.now()}-${uidIndex}`;
  };
};
const generateUniqueId = generate();

const addIdForList = (fileList) => {
  const newFileList = [];
  for (const item of fileList) {
    item._id = generateUniqueId(item.fileName);
    newFileList.push(item);
  }
  return newFileList;
}

console.log(addIdForList(errorListWithTheSameId), 'errorListWithTheSameId');
console.log(addIdForList(correctList), 'correctList');
```

Please have a look at this code. The `normalList` is created by new Array and fill by an object. And the `anotherList` is create directly. And when I use a function to add an id for it, the first array get the same id which is not I expected. Can you explain why this is working this way and how can i fix it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Running `.fill({ ... })` on line 1 is filling the array with two references to the exact same object. So when you pass the array into `addIdForList`, that object is first assigned an id with index `1` and then reassigned an id with index `2`.

Comment: Here is a minimal example demonstrating the same issue: `a = new Array(2).fill({}); a[0].x = 'y'; console.log(a[1].x);  // logs "y"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on the first line. When you run `.fill({ ... })`, you are populating the `errorListWithTheSameId` array with multiple references to the *same* object. Then, when you pass `errorListWithTheSameId` into `addIdForList`, it first assigns that object an id with index `1`, and then again an id with index `2`.

The following is a minimal example of the same issue:

```js
array = new Array(2).fill({});
a = array[0];
b = array[1];
a.x = 10;
console.log(b.x);  // logs 10, whoops!
```

One way to fix this is to change `.fill({ ... })` to `.fill(null).map(() => ({ ... }))`. This works because the function passed into `map` will produce a new object each time it's called.

Answer (score 2):

When you use .fill() the parameter is a reference to the object, so each array element is the same object.

Here's an example of how you can use Array.from() to make sure each array element is different

```js
const normalList = Array.from({
  length: 2
}, () => ({
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions point out the issue with fill duplicating references but I doubt you want to mutate the original arrays at all when you generate `newFileList`

I suggest you map completely new objects instead in `addIdForList()` and leave the originals alone.

I haven't touched the erroneous `fill()` just to demonstrate my point

```js
const errorListWithTheSameId = new Array(2).fill({
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
});

const correctList = [{
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
}, {
  fileName: 'SG100132019.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
}];

const generate = function () {
  let uidIndex = 0;
  return function generateUniqueId(key) {
    uidIndex += 1;
    return `id-${key}-${Date.now()}-${uidIndex}`;
  };
};
const generateUniqueId = generate();

const addIdForList = (fileList) => {  
  return fileList.map(item => {
    const _id = generateUniqueId(item.fileName);
    // return a new object completely
    return {...item, _id};
  });
}

console.log(addIdForList(errorListWithTheSameId), 'errorListWithTheSameId');
console.log(addIdForList(correctList), 'correctList');
```

Comment: Thanks! That is also a way to solve this problem. :)